# Create FileTable Or FileStream SQL Type Use Stream in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stream, filestream, filetable

I wan't to create fileTable or filestream type in SQL Server, but I need to create it from Stream not a Location on disk, Is there any way to do this? any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

use this sample from this [site](https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2011/08/22/using-sqlfilestream-in-c-to-access-sql-server-filestream-data/)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Transactions;

namespace PhotoLibraryApp
{
  public class PhotoData
  {
    private const string ConnStr =
      "Data Source=.;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=PhotoLibrary;";

    public static void InsertPhoto
      (int photoId, string desc, string filename)
    {
      const string InsertTSql = @"
        INSERT INTO PhotoAlbum(PhotoId, Description)
          VALUES(@PhotoId, @Description);
        SELECT Photo.PathName(), GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT()
          FROM PhotoAlbum
          WHERE PhotoId = @PhotoId";

      string serverPath;
      byte[] serverTxn;

      using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
      {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
        {
          conn.Open();

          using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(InsertTSql, conn))
          {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhotoId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = photoId;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = desc;
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
              rdr.Read();
              serverPath = rdr.GetSqlString(0).Value;
              serverTxn = rdr.GetSqlBinary(1).Value;
              rdr.Close();
            }
          }
          SavePhotoFile(filename, serverPath, serverTxn);
        }
        ts.Complete();
      }
    }

    private static void SavePhotoFile
      (string clientPath, string serverPath, byte[] serverTxn)
    {
      const int BlockSize = 1024 * 512;

      using (FileStream source =
        new FileStream(clientPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
        using (SqlFileStream dest =
          new SqlFileStream(serverPath, serverTxn, FileAccess.Write))
        {
          byte[] buffer = new byte[BlockSize];
          int bytesRead;
          while ((bytesRead = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
          {
            dest.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            dest.Flush();
          }
          dest.Close();
        }
        source.Close();
      }
    }

    public static Image SelectPhoto(int photoId, out string desc)
    {
      const string SelectTSql = @"
        SELECT
            Description,
            Photo.PathName(),
            GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT()
          FROM PhotoAlbum
          WHERE PhotoId = @PhotoId";

      Image photo;
      string serverPath;
      byte[] serverTxn;

      using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
      {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
        {
          conn.Open();

          using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SelectTSql, conn))
          {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhotoId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = photoId;

            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
              rdr.Read();
              desc = rdr.GetSqlString(0).Value;
              serverPath = rdr.GetSqlString(1).Value;
              serverTxn = rdr.GetSqlBinary(2).Value;
              rdr.Close();
            }
          }
          photo = LoadPhotoImage(serverPath, serverTxn);
        }

        ts.Complete();
      }

      return photo;
    }

    private static Image LoadPhotoImage(string filePath, byte[] txnToken)
    {
      Image photo;

      using (SqlFileStream sfs =
        new SqlFileStream(filePath, txnToken, FileAccess.Read))
      {
        photo = Image.FromStream(sfs);
        sfs.Close();
      }

      return photo;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: With this example we can retrieve an FileStream type as Stream, but as your link describe we need File path to create FileStram Type: "The first method defined in the class is InsertPhoto, which accepts a new photo integer ID, string description, and full path to an image file to be saved to the database."